# get_user_meta doesn't work in functions.php file

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to get user meta value to use it within functions.php file.

However, it doesn't return anything... in template files like front-page.php it does return correct value, but same function doesn't return anything in functions.php

```
  $postTitle = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'user_registration_company_name', true );
```

$postTitle appears empty... while the below returns value in template files

```
echo get_user_meta( $user_id, 'user_registration_company_name', true );
```

What's the reason for the function to not work from functions.php ?

UPDATE:  get_user_meta($user_id); doesn't even return all of the fields. But, if I call get_user_meta from the template file.. it includes all of them. Any reason for that?

Comment: Try dumping the entire user meta and check whether you get any output. 
 var_dump(get_user_meta( 1 ));

Comment: @akshithDayanand Thanks for the suggestion, I will try that now and let you know.

Comment: Hm.. looks like in functions.php the meta array doesn't even include the fields I need to get. But, if I call get_user_meta from the template file.. it includes them. Any reason for that? @akshithDayanand

Comment: normally the function should return all values available for that particular user id irrespective of the page from where the function is called. One possibility might be that the the value of $user_id passed maybe different in both the cases. Can you verify that?

Comment: @akshithDayanand I use this function in a user_register hook. Apparently, at the point when user has registered those fields are not available. Which is kind or a problem... I need a post created each time user is created. Maybe there's another hook which is called later?

Comment: @vi-progress..So you want to create a post right after the user finishes registration? try this - https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/53328/create-posts-on-user-registration

Comment: @akshithDayanand Yes, I have this solution implemented, but the key problem is that I use "User Registration" plugin for users to sign up. And for some reason, when "user_register" hook is fired, custom meta info (from the registration form fields) are not available yet to access them with get_user_meta();. I can access all meta of previous user on the "user_registration" hook.